# Starting different drivers for tests

Tags: python, appium, python-behave

One of my tests requires a differently configured Android emulator than the other tests. What's the correct way of achieving this? I don't want to start a new emulator for each test, only this 1 test. Something along the lines of:

```
Start emulator 1
  test 1
  test 2
  test 3
Start emulator 2
  test 4
```

Comment: Please edit your question to fit with Stackoverflow guidelines: please provide code to show what you’ve tried, what the specific problems were, and what you having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a variable in the context to track which emulator is active and have each scenario to start the correct emulator if it is not active..  If each test specifies the emulator required as a "given" statement, then the given step implementation can check whether the emulator is active and if not, start it.

```
def before_all(context):
   context.emulator = { 'active': None }

@given('I am using emulator 1'):
def step(context):
   if context.emulator['active'] != 'emulator 1':
       # stop any other emulator, if active
       # start emulator 1
       context.emulator['active'] = 'emulator 1'

@given('I am using emulator 2'):
def step(context):
   if context.emulator['active'] != 'emulator 2':
       # stop any other emulator, if active
       # start emulator 2
       context.emulator['active'] = 'emulator 2'
```

Comment: We start the driver in environment.py with a function that yields the driver object. Would I need to start both drivers in environment.py? This doesn't seem very efficient to me to start a second emulator and have it up for the duration of the test when I only need it for 1 test out of many.